# CodenameOne Eclipse Install Error

Tags: codenameone

I am unable to install CodenameOne on Eclipse (Mars.2 Release 4.5.2).
OS is Yosemite 10.10.4
Update location: http://www.codenameone.com/files/eclipse/site.xml

The error message is:
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=_Users_abc_eclipse_jee-mars_Eclipse.app_Contents_Eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Artifact not found: http:// www.codenameone.com/files/eclipse/plugins/CodenameOnePlugin_1.0.0.201606102329.jar.
http:// www.codenameone.com/files/eclipse/plugins/CodenameOnePlugin_1.0.0.201606102329.jar

Any suggestions?

Comment: that link was broken, try again it should work now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a temporary issue with the latest update that was resolved a couple of hours later.